# Missing tiles in Telerik TileList

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, tilelist

I have 14 tiles in my **TileList** (Telerik). However, only 11 of them are shown on the page. I'm not able to use the space on the bottom right hand corner of the area for some reason. Any idea why it might cause this problem?

**Screenshot:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
<telerik:RadTileList ID="RadTileList1" runat="server" TileRows="4" Width="100%" EnableDragAndDrop="True" SelectionMode="Multiple">
    <Groups>
        <telerik:TileGroup>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[0,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[0,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[0,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[0,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[1,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[1,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[1,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[1,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[4,2] %>" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[4,0] %>" Width="310px" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[4,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[4,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[7,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[7,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[7,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[7,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[8,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[8,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[8,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[8,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[2,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[2,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[2,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[2,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[3,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[3,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[3,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[3,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[5,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[5,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[5,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[5,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[6,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[6,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[6,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[6,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[9,2] %>" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[9,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[9,1] %>" Target="_blank" ImageWidth="150px" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[9,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageAndTextTile runat="server" EnableSelection="True" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[10,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[10,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[10,1] %>" Target="_blank">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[10,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageAndTextTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" EnableSelection="True" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[11,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[11,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[11,1] %>" Target="_blank">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[11,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ForeColor="White" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[12,2] %>" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[12,0] %>" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[12,1] %>" Target="_blank" ImageWidth="150px" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[12,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
            <telerik:RadImageTile runat="server" ImageHeight="150px" ImageUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[13,2] %>" ImageWidth="150px" Name="<%$ Code: allTiles[13,0] %>" ForeColor="White" NavigateUrl="<%$ Code: allTiles[13,1] %>" Target="_blank" EnableSelection="True">
                <Title Text="<%$ Code: allTiles[13,0] %>"></Title>
            </telerik:RadImageTile>
        </telerik:TileGroup>
    </Groups>
</telerik:RadTileList>
```

Comment: have you tried looking at the [Telerik Documentation - Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/tilelist/examples/overview/defaultcs.aspx)

Comment: I had spent some time on that demo. There 3 rows there. Everything is good with 3 rows in my project as well. The moment I go to 4th row (which I have to based on my requirements), I run into this issue... I've also posted it in Telerik forums but it's been added into approval queue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. RadPersistenceManager was the reason. It was loading a state which was saved for 3 rows in Page_Load. I've changed the saved state.